# Como verificar se um nó XML é nulo?

Tags: c#, xml

Tenho um *WS* que possui um método no qual é inserida uma lista de Nós com alguns dados. Recebo esses estes dados como *XmlDocument*, percorro o nó *Parameters* lendo o conteúdo dentro dele, depois disso pego os dados e preencho os parâmetros da minha *Procedure* pra inserir na base. 
Porém existe a possibilidade de caso o dado enviado via *WS* seja nulo, o nó não seja criado, e quando tento ler o nó da erro.
De qual forma eu posso verificar se o nó existe e caso não inserir *NULL* no parâmetro da *Procedure*?

Segue o código que estou usando para validar isto, porém o mesmo retorna erro

```
cmdMailingRetorno.Parameters.AddWithValue(
        "@DataHoraFim",
        Telefones[i]["DataHoraFim"].HasAttributes ?
            (DateTime?)null :
            Convert.ToDateTime(Telefones[i]["DataHoraFim"].InnerText)
);
```

Comment: Não entendi, quando o valor é `null` você recebe `null` no node ou ele não existe?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo pelo que eu entendi, o nó não existe na resposta.

Comment: Reescrevendo um desserializador de xml. É exatamente isso que ele faz. A partir de um objeto, alimenta os campos que forem declarados no xml e deixa com o valor padrão os que não forem.

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de caso o dado enviado  seja null o nó não seja criado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua validação está inversa se `Telefones[i]["DataHoraFim"].HasAttributes` for true, você está atribuindo `(DateTime?)null` como valor do seu parâmetro. Você também pode verificar se o node existe também antes de verificar se ele possui atributos, o que também não faz muito sentido pois você está esperando recuperar o valor escrito dentro do nó.

Então você precisa verificar se o nó existe e se o `InnerText` é null ou possui algum valor.

```
cmdMailingRetorno.Parameters.AddWithValue(
      "@DataHoraFim",
      (Telefones[i]["DataHoraFim"] == null || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(["DataHoraFim"].InnerText))
      ? null 
      : Convert.ToDateTime(Telefones[i]["DataHoraFim"].InnerText)
);
```

Comment: obtive o seguinte erro : Seqüência não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido,ele não aceita como null ?

Comment: tinha esquecido de tirar... você não deve passar um `DateTime?` para o parâmetro, se é `null` é `null`. Agora esse erro pode ser na conversão do `Telefones[i]["DataHoraFim"].InnerText`, ele aconteceu em um nó com ou sem valor?

Comment: Agora deu certo amigo,Tive sim que usar `(DateTime?)null`                    caso contrario dava erro de conversão : Não há conversão implicita entre "<nulo> " e "DateTime"